# Incrementing values of potentially empty keys of a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a more correct way to do the following:

```
if a in dic.keys():
    dic[a] += 1
else:
    dic[a] = 1
```

I.e. to increment values corresponding to keys in a dictionary, when those keys may not be present.

Comment: How do you loop over a dict keys, but then encounter keys that are not present?

Comment: that's what happens when you paste in code but change it to be more generic, and then don't read it properly before submitting.. I edited out the iteration (which makes sense in the original context)

Comment: There's no single "correct" way, but `defaultdict` is the fastest, IIRC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to provide a default value for keys not present in the dictionary.

```
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> d[1] += 1
>>> d[1]
    1
>>> d[5]
    0
```

Comment: i only want entries for keys who's value is > 0

Comment: What do you mean? A defaultdict handles the situation presented in the question.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.get#dict.get):

```
dic[a] = dic.get(a, 0) + 1
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  It's odd syntax though tbh - a little low on readability

Comment: @trideceth12 What is lacking in readability? What would you like to have?

Comment: Is this better than the validated answer? On a first hand, an import is required, on the other, the syntax is sliightly different.

Answer (score 2):

You could use collections.Counter()

```
dic = collections.Counter()
dic['a'] += 1
dic['b'] # will be zero
```

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: I ended up using this, but the accepted answer is more generally applicable

Comment: True, but Counter provides other niceties. For instance, you can add two Counter objects.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `dict.setdefault()`:

```
In [12]: dic=dict(zip(('a','b'),[0]*2))

In [13]: dic
Out[13]: {'a': 0, 'b': 0}

In [14]: dic['c']=dic.setdefault('c',0)+1

In [15]: dic
Out[15]: {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}

In [16]: dic['a']=dic.setdefault('a',0)+1

In [17]: dic
Out[17]: {'a': 1, 'b': 0, 'c': 1}
```

using a loop:

```
In [18]: dic=dict(zip(('a','b'),[0]*2))

In [19]: for x in ('a','b','c','a'):
   ....:     dic[x]=dic.setdefault(x,0)+1
   ....:     

In [20]: dic
Out[20]: {'a': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1}
```